# Storing booleans in Preferences

Tags: android, libgdx, preferences

Im struggling to grasp how to store/read booleans from preferences in LIBGDX. What Im using them for is if the user have bought an item, then the boolean should turn true and be stored as true until a different boolean is turned true , then the first one will be turned false. Hope Im exlpaining myself in an understandable way.

This is what I´ve done:

Screen where they make the purchase and presses the button to make the change:

```
PurcScreen implements Screen {
changeStone1.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            ss.prefs.getBoolean("stone1", true);
            game.setScreen(ss);
        }

    });
```

And this is the screen where the object they have purchased should be drawn depending on wether or not the boolean is true/false:

```
MainScreen implements Screen {
public boolean stone1, stone2
public MainScreen {
stone1 = prefs.getBoolean("stone1");
stone2 = prefs.getBoolean("stone2");
if(stone1){
    setStone1();

    }
    if(stone2){
        setStone2();
    }
show() {
if(stone1) {
        setStone2();
        prefs.putBoolean("stone1", true);
        prefs.putBoolean("stone2", false);
}
if(stone2) {
        setStone2();
        prefs.putBoolean("stone1", false);
        prefs.putBoolean("stone2", true);
}
btnSave.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
@override
public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
prefs.putBoolean("stone1", stone1);
prefs.putBoolean("stone2", stone2);
prefs.flush();
}
```

With this code, the booleans arn´t stored. stone2´s image/object is drawn. But as I click savebutton and re-enter the screen the original stone1 object is drawn again.

Comment: This is not an answer but I would just like to mention that if you want to avoid cheating, using LibGDX's built in preferences is not the best way, especially if you plan on deploying to desktop. On desktop, all the player will have to do is edit a simple XML file and change the value to true. I would suggest creating you're own saving system and encrypting it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Im noy deploying to desktop though.

Comment: Bradley , commit() isn´t no more. That´s from an old libgdx version.

Comment: noted, changed my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your preferences object from the framework (make sure you get the same name when reading and writing)

```
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("My Preferences");
```

Save a boolean to the prefs object:

```
prefs.putBoolean("soundOn", true);
prefs.flush();
```

Read the boolean from the prefs object:

```
prefs.getBoolean("soundOn");
```

Reference wiki:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences

Comment: So the string/value "soundOn" will act as a boolean? I dont need to actually declare a boolean an connect it to the string like boolean soundOn = prefs.putBoolean("soundOn", true) ? And If so ,can I do if(prefs.getBoolean("soundOn"){do stuff} ?

Comment: The string "soundOn" is just a key to a boolean value. prefs.getBoolean("soundOn") will return the actual boolean value. So yes, you can do this - if (prefs.getBoolean("soundOn")){do stuff}.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ensure you've imported the correct `.flush` dependency, there is one in both Android and Java.

Try `.apply()` instead of `.flush()`

Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply())

> As SharedPreferences instances are singletons within a process, it's safe to replace any instance of commit() with apply() if you were already ignoring the return value.

[Further Reading](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33375/pass-a-single-boolean-from-an-android-app-to-a-libgdx-game)

Comment: Srry. I didn´t include that I use Libgdx framework. They have their own method for storing preferences.